# One and Two photos galleries breaking PhotoSwipe

Tags: photoswipe

Photoswipe don't know to handle galleries of one or two images.

If it tries to run a single or 2 images galleries, Photoswipe breaks, displaying the carousel container, but don't show buttons and don't swipe to sides.

Anyone got any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected photoswipe's code, and created a pull request to photoswipe repository.

Solution is to fix wrong code inside the plugin

```
* Function: isLikeArray
         */
        isLikeArray: function(obj) { 
 -          return typeof obj.length === 'number';
 +          try {
 +              return typeof obj.length === 'number';
 +          } catch (e) {
 +              return false;
 +          }
        },
```

https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/pull/640